# Dynamic errors on Angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to get Angular reactive forms, within an Ionic mobile app, to show the validation errors relevant to each field. All the tutorials I have read specifically name each field and validator which doesn't sound very dynamic to me.

This is the template I have so far

```
<ion-input *ngIf="property.component == 'number'"
    type="number" [attr.id]="property.id"
    [formControlName]="property.label">
</ion-input>
```

I have components for number, text, date etc. This code creates the form group that is used by the template

```
private createFormGroup = (question: SurveyQuestion) => {

    const formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        [question.label]: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
    const items = formGroup.get(question.label) as FormArray;
    question.properties.forEach((property, index) => {

        let validatorArray = [];

        if (!property.is_optional)
        {
            validatorArray.push(Validators.required);
        }

        //Other validators are added to array here

        items.push(this.formBuilder.group({
            [property.label]: new FormControl("",  Validators.compose(validatorArray))
        }))
    });

    return formGroup;

};
```

As you can see each FormControl has an array of validators controlled by the database.

**How do I modify the template to report the errors for each field without prior knowledge of the validators attached to it?**

Comment: You can create a component that takes the form control's errors as input, and iterates through the errors, displaying an error message for each one. https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#errors

Comment: @JBNizet I've now got a basic template working, if you'd post your response as an answer I'll mark it as correct and show some code